# Is there a way to use dynamic values in pytest parameterization?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a large table test that I want to use in pytest (an array of some parameters and an expected value). I want to run a setup for this test only, then calculate the expected values, and use that as parametrized input to my test. I realize probably the right answer is having static expected values, but I really like the ability to compute them.

First, I had it all within the test and setup in a fixture for that test, which worked fine, but only acted as a single test.  So then I parameterized, but I can't calculate the expected values after setup that way (it gets run at collection time, before setup).  Then I put it in `pytest_generate_tests(metafunc)` to parametrize, which *almost* worked, except I needed to run the setup inside that to make sure it ran before calculation.  And that end up running every time, because the test is collected even if it's not run.

Current method:

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if "filter_test" not in metafunc.fixturenames:
        return
    db_setup()
    ... calulate expected values ...
    metafunc.parametrize('filter_test', [list of tests])

def test_filtering(filter_test):
  ...
```

So basically, want to run a setup only when this test gets run, and be able to calculate values to use as parameters for my test.

Comment: You can compute the values at the top of your module and save them to global variable and then parametrize your tests with this variable. Not the best method, but will surely work. See also this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35211606/pytest-parameterized-method-setup?rq=1